# Prints not sticking to centre of build plate, Phenom Peopoly

Tags: resin

Recently prints aren't sticking to centre of bed - e.g if I print a grid of 25 identical models, the ones in centre will not attach to build plate.  Models near edges stick to build plate fine, on all 4 sides, plate is levelled fine.  No visible damage to screen, models on sides print fine and the models in centre stick to the FEP.  Previously printer worked fine.

Things tried:

1. Cleaning build plate with IPA and also with acetone to ensure
   degreased.
2. Cleaning FEP with alcohol
3. Replaced FEP
4. Tried adding PTFE
   spray (v small amount) to film to encourage less sticking, issue
   persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your build surface to see if it's still flat? Repeated center-focused cleanings may have eroded the center of the plate enough to make a difference.